# Filter the FALSE in the all colums in data.frame with R

Tags: r, dplyr, filter, many-to-many, multiple-columns

I want to filter the value FALSE in all of the column in the data frame.

My data frame contains 40 column. Each column contains **TRUE** or **FALSE** or **NA**

```
df1 <- data.frame(id=1:10, col1=c(T, F, NA, T, F, F, NA, NA, F, T), col2=c(T, T, F, F, NA, T, F, NA, F, T),col3=c(F, F, NA, NA, NA, T, T, F, F, T))

   id  col1  col2  col3
1   1  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
2   2 FALSE  TRUE FALSE
3   3    NA FALSE    NA
4   4  TRUE FALSE    NA
5   5 FALSE    NA    NA
6   6 FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
7   7    NA FALSE  TRUE
8   8    NA    NA FALSE
9   9 FALSE FALSE FALSE
10 10  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
```

I just want to filter the FALSE in the all column.

Thank you for your help

It's easy if my column is under 10, but my column have 40.

Comment: It helps when the data you provide _works_. In this case, it's a parsing error. I appreciate that you are providing sample data (instead of dumping lots of other data), please take a moment when doing so to test to make sure you get what you need with your sample data. I'm editing in the fixes now.

Comment: What is the expected output? Are you trying to filter out rows with only FALSE values, in this case row 9? Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/q/66548590/680068

Comment: @zx8754, that link won't work with `NA`s in it. We can still use `rowSums`, though ...

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can use the following approach with `dplyr` based on [this question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67257561/rowwise-logical-operations-with-mutate-and-filter-in-r):

- `Reduce` with `|` does a logical OR with all columns (rowwise) which is only FALSE when all elements in the row are FALSE
- `!` inverts it, therefore `filter` only selects the rows where all elements are FALSE

```r
df1 <- data.frame(id=1:10, col1=c(T, F, NA, T, F, F, NA, NA, F, T), col2=c(T, T, F, F, NA, T, F, NA, F, T),col3=c(F, F, NA, NA, NA, T, T, F, F, T))

library(dplyr)

df1 %>% 
  filter(!Reduce(`|`, select(., col1:col3)))
#>   id  col1  col2  col3
#> 1  9 FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

<sup>Created on 2023-05-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

Comment: The problem with this is that `|` is not working with the `NA` values. While `df1` starts with 10 rows, this returns one row and the negation (`filter(Reduce(...))`) returns 6 rows, this filter is unable to accommodate the other 4 rows.

Comment: I understood that only the rows with only `FALSE` should be filtered, here only row 9. I agree that it is not optimal that `Reduce` returns `NA` instead of `TRUE/FALSE`, however with my version of `dplyr` `NA` is also treated as `FALSE`, leading to the correct filtering

Comment: Hehe, sure, and I think I'm banking on the interpretation of (or at least the option to) "filter **out** all-false rows", not "filter **retain**". Good point.

Comment: Good point, this totally went over my head. I usually understand "filter" as "I want to retain these values". Again shows how important it is to include the expected output in the question!

Answer (score 0):

Since this involves a lot of `NA` values that confound the simple use of `rowSums`, we can add the use of `%in%`:

## base R

```r
df1[rowSums(!sapply(df1[-1], `%in%`, FALSE)) > 0,]
#    id  col1  col2  col3
# 1   1  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
# 2   2 FALSE  TRUE FALSE
# 3   3    NA FALSE    NA
# 4   4  TRUE FALSE    NA
# 5   5 FALSE    NA    NA
# 6   6 FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
# 7   7    NA FALSE  TRUE
# 8   8    NA    NA FALSE
# 10 10  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
```

Alternatively, thanks zx8754:

```r
df1[ rowSums(df1[ , 2:4] == FALSE, na.rm = TRUE) != 3, ]
```

## dplyr

```r
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
  filter(!if_all(col1:col3, ~ . %in% FALSE))
#   id  col1  col2  col3
# 1  1  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
# 2  2 FALSE  TRUE FALSE
# 3  3    NA FALSE    NA
# 4  4  TRUE FALSE    NA
# 5  5 FALSE    NA    NA
# 6  6 FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
# 7  7    NA FALSE  TRUE
# 8  8    NA    NA FALSE
# 9  9 FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

Comment: Any good reason for using sapply? `df1[ rowSums(df1[ , 2:4] == FALSE, na.rm = TRUE) != 3, ]`

Comment: that works too, but my use of `%in%` doesn't work on whole frames; I think I like yours better .. which takes this closer to the dupe-link :-)

Comment: the biggest "other" to your code is that it hard-codes the number of columns, I was trying to avoid that as well

Comment: It can be fixed with colnames and grep, feel free to edit with my version, and close as dupe if you wish.

Comment: already edited (refresh!), thanks

Comment: Thank you very much @r2evans, and **zx8754** for your help. It's work for me the base.